# Как добавить несколько ограничений при изменении таблицы? ORA-01735: invalid ALTER TABLE option

Tags: sql, oracle, constraints

Есть ли возможность добавить сразу несколько ограничений в таблицу командой `ALTER TABLE`?

Знаю, что подобное возможно в SQL Server:

```
ALTER TABLE l_customer_order 
    ADD CONSTRAINT pk_l_customer_order 
        PRIMARY KEY (customer_order_id_hk),
    CONSTRAINT fk_customer_id_hk 
        FOREIGN KEY (customer_id_hk) 
        REFERENCES h_customers(customer_id_hk)
        ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT fk_order_id_hk 
        FOREIGN KEY (order_id_hk) 
        REFERENCES h_orders(order_id_hk)
        ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Но получаю ошибку:

> ORA-01735: invalid ALTER TABLE option

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Adding multiple constraints in ORACLE using ALTER TABLE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60719075) от участника [@Maeaex1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9476917/maeaex1)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/60719075

Answer (score 5):

Заключите все добавляемые ограничения в круглые скобки:

```
create table t (c1 int, c2 int, c3 int);
    
alter table t
    add ( 
        constraint pk primary key ( c1 ),
        constraint ck check ( c2 > 0 )
    )
/
select constraint_name 
from user_constraints
where table_name = 'T';

CONSTRAINT_NAME
----------------
CK
PK
```

---

*Прим.ред.:* Отсутвие скобок на [синтаксической диаграмме](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/ALTER-TABLE.html#GUID-552E7373-BF93-477D-9DA3-B2C9386F2877__I2103997) скорее всего ошибка в документации.

---

<sub>Свободный перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60719136) от участника [@Chris Saxon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1485955/chris-saxon)</sub>